# DynamoDB query timeout/no response on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am using https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels to connect to DynamoDB. All works fine from my local env but on ec2 it times out and sends no response when I query. Although I can connect and list tables with vogels with no problem. Additionally I tried aws-cli and it works fine.

Is there a change in API? why I can connect from my local env but not from ec2 with the same config?
Update:
This issue started today although no code changes on my end
I just noticed there was a release today (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2650)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to CentOS 7 instead of Amazon linux and all works fine!